# Отправка формы яндекс кассы

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

Есть интернет-магазин самописный. К нему один программист приделал яндекс кассу. Но иногда клиенты жалуются, что при выборе оплаты на сайте, страница подвисает. Экспериментально было выявлено, что дело именно в отправке формы яндекс кассы. Она была сделана как-то очень странно.

```
private function __getYandexForm($id, $total) {
    return '
    <form name="ShopForm" id="yandexForm" method="POST" action="'. $this->action_url .'"style="display:none">

        <input type="hidden" name="shopId" value="' . $this->shopid . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="scid" value="' . $this->shid . '">

        Идентификатор клиента/Номер заказа:<br>
        <input type=text name="customerNumber" size="74" value="' . $id . '"><br><br>
        Сумма:<br>
        <input type=text name="Sum" size="74" value="' . $total . '"><br><br>
        Способ оплаты:<br><br>
        <input name="paymentType" value="PC" type="radio" >Оплата со счета в Яндекс.Деньгах (комиссия 3%)<br>
        <input name="paymentType" value="AC" type="radio" checked>Оплата банковской картой (комиссия 3.5%)<br>
        <br><input type=submit value="Оплатить"><br>
    </form>

    <script>
        jQuery("form#yandexForm").submit();
    </script>';
}
```

То есть по сути скрипт возвращает на страницу сам форму яндекса вместе с jquery-скриптом, имитирующий отправку этой сгенерированной формы. И вот именно этот шаг иногда не у всех срабатывает.

Возможно ли как-то по-человечески это переделать? У кого опыт с яндекс-кассой был?

Comment: А если попробовать отправлять форму когда вся страница загрузится? Т.е. отправлять форму только по событию загрузки страницы (например, на "load").

Comment: да, можно, но все равно как-то костыльно...

Comment: на мой взгляд генерировать яваскрипт таким образом достаточно костыльно. Но вы всё же попробуйте, вдруг сработает.